# Reversing byte substitution in an image file

Tags: python, image, jpeg, corruption

I have a large number of corrupted JPG files. The command  `sed -i 's/;/_/g'` was run on them, which changed the semicolons (0x3b) in the JPG files to underscores (0x5f.)

This is a Python code I wrote to change 0x5F back to 0x3B in all possible cases, but the number of cases was astronomical and I had to stop the process. Is there a better approach to solve this problem?

```py
with open(inPath + "error.jpg", "rb") as f:
    img_data = f.read()

# SOS Marker position
sos_pos = img_data.find(b"\xff\xda")
sos_data = img_data[:sos_pos] #SO Smarker 
img_data = bytearray(img_data[sos_pos:]) #image data

# count 5f
count = img_data.count(0x5F)
print(f"0x5F 총 갯수 : {count}")

# 5F position in image data
indices = [i for i, x in enumerate(img_data) if x == 0x5F]

print("start")
print(len(indices))

idx = 0

for i in indices :
    img_data[i] = 0x3B
    print(i)

    for combination in itertools.permutations(indices, 2):
        idx += 1        
        with open(outPath + str(idx) + '.jpg', "wb") as f:
            f.write(sos_data + img_data)

print("end")
```

[Here is a sample image showing the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fNYrI.jpg)

Comment: So why not reverse that sed command?

Comment: @g00se Well *how*?

Comment: Actually looking at your example, I'm guessing that there's more wrong than just a single substitution, as reversing it makes zero *effective* difference

Comment: @g00se I don't understand. The original image data area had both 0x5F and 0x3B, but now, after the conversion, only 0x5F values are present and there is no 0x3B. If I reverse the conversion as you suggest, the original 0x5F value will be lost.

Comment: Oh yes, that was silly of me. I'd overlooked the *legitimate* 0x5f values in the file. But my point still stands really. Why? There's are only nine instances of that value in that jpg file. The first one occurs around offset 161. I don't know much about exif files, but am going to guess that is not within metadata. So even allowing for most of those 0x5f values having already been there, the image is still too corrupt-looking to *only* have been caused by the sed accident

Comment: @g00se The sample image is a small-sized image that I uploaded after modifying it with a Hex Editor for demonstration purposes. Your suggestion is also something that I've considered, and I will try it. Thank you

Comment: @g00se How did you count 19? I get 434 with `requests.get('https://i.stack.imgur.com/fNYrI.jpg').content.count(b'\x5f')`.

Comment: Sorry - that was wrong. Have deleted it

Comment: I get what you get (434): `tr -dc '\137' < new.jpg | wc -c`

Comment: Changing those all back to 0x3B makes no real difference

Comment: Instead of writing the image to file, why not just try to process it with an image library like pillow? If an exception isn't thrown, you have a valid image.

Comment: @miken32 Does that have no false positives or false negatives?

Comment: @KellyBundy I have no idea, I'm not much of a Python guy. I have to assume if the image can be opened by pillow without errors there's a good chance of it being salvageable. And possibly that library or another has methods to check image integrity.

Comment: I guess my original comment should have said "you *may* have a valid image"